# Proof of multidimensional generalization of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f$ is continuous function on $B =I_1 \times I_2 \times\cdots\times I_n$
where the $I_i$ are closed intervals in $\mathbb R$ and $σ \colon \{1,2,...,n\}\to\{1,2,...,n\}$ is a one-to-one permutation.

Show that $$ \int_B f(x)\, dx = \int_{I_{σ(n)}} \int_{I_{σ(n-1)}} \cdots \int_{I_{σ(1)}}  f(x)\,dx_{σ(1)} \ldots dx_{σ(n)}.$$

---

I don't know if this is an extension of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem, but it looks similar.

If I understood a proof of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem, would I easily understand this problem?

Comment: Even if you do not remember the proof for Fubini theorem, I believe you can derive this from the statement of Fubini theorem.

Comment: I try to derive this by using induction. Its just simple if i know proof of Fubini theorem, right? if so, i have a question. Can we sure that the F defined in Fubini theorem is continuous function?

Comment: In Fubinii theorem, the function $f$ only needs to be absolute integrable with respect to the product measure. This assumption holds trivially here since the domain is a compact set (a box) and the function is continuous.

Comment: Well... its difficult to me. :(

Comment: There is purportedly a [Fubini-Tonelli theorem for triple integral](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/15%3A_Multiple_Integration/15.4%3A_Triple_Integrals), however no proof is provided.

Comment: There is purportedly a [Fubini-Tonelli theorem for multiple dimensions](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Book%3A_Introduction_to_Real_Analysis_(Lebl)/11%3A_Multivariable_Integral/11.02%3A_Iterated_integrals_and_Fubini_theorem), however no proof is provided for this general case.